# JSX Mapping a dynamic array of objects to display MDL menus

Tags: reactjs, material-design, jsx

I am attempting to build a basic ReactJS app that will be utilizing Material Design Lite. Below is a code sample (using demo content from the Material docs) from within the React component `return()` statement. It does not seem to be rendering menu items properly. When you click the menu icon, the list of actions should pop up, but nothing happens here. If placed outside of the `map()` function as a standalone element (with changes to make it static), it appears without issue. Any help debugging would be appreciated!

**Expected output:**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa81O.png)

**Code notes:**
[MDL doc for this component](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section)
this.state.rooms = [ {Obj 1}, {Obj 2}, {Obj 3} ]
keys are unique to each object and already a property

```
{this.state.rooms.map( room => {
  return (
    <div className="room-row" key={room.key}>
      <button id={"demo-menu-lower-left" + room.key} className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
        <i className="material-icons">more_vert</i>
      </button>

      <ul className="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" htmlFor={"demo-menu-lower-left" + room.key}>
        <li className="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
        <li className="mdl-menu__item mdl-menu__item--full-bleed-divider">Another Action</li>
        <li disabled className="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
        <li className="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   )}
```

**Live React DOM of room index 0:**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uupOf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a single Javascript object HTML/Jsx Tag containing all of the content.
With your actual function, i suppose you are returning an array of elements with **room.length** divs, being this element **room**.
Try to return only one object, that has all of the divs, like this:

```
{ var renderedDivs = [];

  renderedDivs = this.state.rooms.map( room => {
      return (
        <div className="room-row" key={room.key}>
          <button id={"demo-menu-lower-left" + room.key} className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
        <i className="material-icons">more_vert</i>
      </button>

      <ul className="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" htmlFor={"demo-menu-lower-left" + room.key}>
        <li className="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
        <li className="mdl-menu__item mdl-menu__item--full-bleed-divider">Another Action</li>
        <li disabled className="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
        <li className="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   )
  return renderedDivs
```

}

Or another thing that might work:

```
{return (this.state.rooms.map( room => {
  return (
    <div className="room-row" key={room.key}>
      <button id={"demo-menu-lower-left" + room.key} className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
        <i className="material-icons">more_vert</i>
      </button>

      <ul className="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" htmlFor={"demo-menu-lower-left" + room.key}>
        <li className="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
        <li className="mdl-menu__item mdl-menu__item--full-bleed-divider">Another Action</li>
        <li disabled className="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
        <li className="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   ))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I actually already have my code snippet wrapped inside one single tag, i just did not show that part in my question. The buttons do show up on the page for each index, however for some reason the actions do not tie to it as expected.

Comment: Is the style being applied correctly?   
I think that your problem lies in the MDL library, it does not work out of the box for React, you might need to use another library, or use the one ported:  
Example of another library:   
https://material-ui.com/  
Example of the MDL ported to React (Material-ui looks more solid): 
https://tleunen.github.io/react-mdl/components/